# ruby script syncftp: mime/type not found

Tags: ruby, windows, mime

I have a ruby script (syncftp from Github) that contains the following instruction:
require 'mime/types'
This file is not found. (All other includes are found.) I use ruby 2.1. Where can I get this file?

Comment: You should to install [mime-types gem](https://github.com/halostatue/mime-types). To do this run `gem install mime-types`

Comment: Thanks! Done, file can be included now but ruby reports a new error

C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mime-types-2.1/lib/mime/type.rb:30:in `<t
op (required)>': uninitialized constant MIME (NameError)